# What is an alternative word for saying "A new trend in technology" or "Trending technology"

Tags: word-choice

What is an alternative word for saying "A new trend in technology" or "Trending technology". Can you suggest some word that I could use as a title for a seminar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on exactly what you're talking about and the desired tone, you might talk about "developments" in technology, "advances", "frontiers" (a little grandiose), "the latest" (rather informal), "the leading edge" or "the cutting edge" (those are becoming MBA-speak -- somewhat pretentious), "fads" (implying these are trends that will die before long), or "hottest new" (usually reserved for sales pitches).

Answer (score 0):

This seems catchy to me!

> A new trend in technology - can be broad and may cover many aspects in technology. 
> Trending technology - is focused and used for particular technology.

Check these examples:

> eCommerce is a new trend in technology for the online retailers. 
>   In eCommerce, responsive web design is trending technology.

However, using the word 'trending' fits and conveys the message without any ambiguity. Because the word *trending* itself is *trending!* Anything that's latest, on the rage these days can be referred to as trending. For instance, in social media, *trending* is widely used these days whether it's #followfriday or #throwbackthursday etc.

Another phrase I've come across is *emerging technology* that may not **exactly** mean *trending* but may be used.

To sum it up -

Use 'Trending Technology' if you are talking about *one particular technology* and if you are talking about what all is *in* these days in the world of technology, go for *A New Trend in Technology*